# How to get last one week data from mongo collection where date is stored in string format?

Tags: string, mongodb, date

I am using mongoDB version 3.4 .
I have a collection where date is stored in String format `YYYY-mm-dd`.   I need to get last week data from this collection.

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-7))
```

returns me the date in ISO date format , which cannot be used to compare with date in string format.
I cannot use date formatter as it is not supported by version 3.4.
Is there a way to get current date is in string format and use it in the query?
And also , I need only date , without timestamp.

Comment: try using ```$dateToString``` it is supported starting from version 3.0

Comment: `$dateToString` will convert the ISODate object saved in the database to string. But the op has strings in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
var today = new Date();
var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
var firstDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first));
var lastDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first + 6));


db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        date: {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: '$date'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "date": {
            $lt: lastDayWeek,
            $gt: firstDayWeek
        }
    }
}])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aaf77510f1ae49ecac9c1a7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-20T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways I can think of.

Most easiest will be calculating different dates in the last week, converting them to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and then just comparing strings.

```
var listOfDates = ["2018-02-19","2018-02-18","2018-02-17","2018-02-16"]

collection.find(date:{$in:listOfDates})
```

**Alternative:**
Convert all dates to standard ISODate type and then use normal queries. The conversion will only be one time, and it would be the right thing to do. You will be even able to use indexes to get faster results.

```
db.mycol.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.date = new Date(doc.date)    
    db.mycol.save(doc);    
})
```

This will convert `{"date" : "2018-02-19"}` to `{"date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T00:00:00Z")}`

Please note that `"2018-02-19"` will be the UTC date, so you might have to do some conversion based on your timezone.

Comment: What is the way to convert all string date entries to ISO Date format ?

Comment: you will just have to fire an update query targeting all of the records, replacing the existing value with `new Date(existingValue)`

Comment: @Ms_Bee I've updated my answer with the necessary code. Please note that the date will be UTC date.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var week_1 = new Date(); // current date
```

//here you can use your date instate of current date

```
        var pastDate = week_1.getDate() - 7;
        week_1.setDate(pastDate);
         

        collection.find({"createdAt": {
                $gte: week_1
            }})
```